# Converting a unicode string to see unicode code points

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have this:

```
>>> su = u'"/\"'
```

In python, how can I convert this to a representation that shows the unicode code points? That would be this for the string above

```
u'\u0022\u002F\u005C\u0022'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original string is not four characters but three because `\"` is an escape code for a double quote:

```
>>> su = u'"/\"'
>>> len(su)
3
```

Here's how to display it as escape codes:

```
>>> ''.join(u'\\u{:04X}'.format(ord(c)) for c in su)
u'\\u0022\\u002F\\u0022'
```

Use a Unicode raw string, or double backslashes to escape the slash and get four characters:

```
>>> su = ur'"/\"' # Raw version
>>> ''.join(u'\\u{:04X}'.format(ord(c)) for c in su)
u'\\u0022\\u002F\\u005C\\u0022'

>>> su = u'"/\\"' # Escaped version
>>> ''.join(u'\\u{:04X}'.format(ord(c)) for c in su)
u'\\u0022\\u002F\\u005C\\u0022'
```

Note the double backslash in the result.  This indicates it is a single literal backslash.  with one backslash, they would be escape codes...no different from your original string:

```
>>> ur'"/\"' == u'\u0022\u002F\u005C\u0022'
True
```

Printing it shows the content of the strings:

```
>>> print u'\u0022\u002F\u005C\u0022'
"/\"
>>> print(''.join(u'\\u{:04X}'.format(ord(c)) for c in su))
\u0022\u002F\u005C\u0022
```

Comment: Why do I need to use ur (unicode raw) ? It works well for me without using ur version of the string.

Comment: You don't, if you intended to escape the `"` in the first place.  Still a bit of a confusing example, however.

Comment: @abc is your intended string `"/"` or `"/\"`.  Putting a \ character in an example string, especially before a character that can be escaped (such as `"`) without clarifying intention results in this confusion.

Comment: @metatoaster Actually I was confused myself. Looks like my string is 3 chars long not 4. So my string is "/".

Comment: @abc: note: the above works only for BMP characters e.g., it may fail an emoji such as `u''` ([U+1f600](http://codepoints.net/U+1f600))

Answer (score 1):

To support the full Unicode range, you could use `unicode-escape` to get the text representation. To represent characters in the ascii range as the unicode escapes too and to force `\u00xx` representation even for `u'\xff'`, you could use a regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re

su = u'"/"\U000af600'
assert u'\ud800' not in su # no lone surrogate
print re.sub(ur'[\x00-\xff]', lambda m: u"\ud800u%04x" % ord(m.group()), su, 
             flags=re.U).encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\ud800', '\\')
```

a lone surrogate (U+d800) is used to avoid escaping the backslash twice.

#### Output

```
\u0022\u002f\u0022\U000af600
```